# Trying to run Spacy Textual entailment example and getting a value error (keras)

Tags: spacy

Hi guys I'm trying to run the spacy example for textual entailment. I've got all the requirements installed, and i'm trying to run the preliminary test..

```
py.test keras_parikh_entailment/keras_decomposable_attention.py
```

I get the error

```
 ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "embed" with a  weight list of length 1, but the layer was expecting 0 weights. Provided weights: [array([[  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.4...

../../../.virtualenvs/nlp3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py
```

Should be something pretty simple, any help is appreciated.